# Why I'm getting unexpected result from strcmp function in c

Tags: c, string.h

I have made a game and this is the last part when a player is required to type yes/no to paly again. But the result of this code is unexpected.
Code:

```
do{
    setbuf(stdout, NULL);
    printf("\nDo you want to play again(yes/no)");
    scanf("%s", &yn);
}while(strcmp(yn, "yes")==0||strcmp(yn, "no")==0);
```

Result:

```
Do you want to play again(yes/no) no
Do you want to play again(yes/no) yes
Do you want to play again(yes/no) random
Do you want to play again(yes/no)
```

Its repeating over and over.

Can you fix this code?

Comment: Is the loop to make sure that the user inputs either `"yes"` or `"no"`? And that the loop should end when the input is `"yes"` or `"no"`? Then it's wrong. Please take some time with a pen and paper to think about what the loop condition needs to be.

Comment: I also recommend you take some time to learn [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) on how to properly negate logical conditions.

Comment: Could you show us where `yn` is declared?

Comment: `yn` is already a pointer (or equivalent) so there's no need to take its address for `scanf`. `scanf("%s", yn)`.

Comment: @Schwern We don't know what `yn` really is. And if it *is* a pointer, then the OP have much worse problems than the loop condition. But without a proper [mre] it's really impossible to say anything for certain.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives. This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste.

Comment: Since you are not showing us what `YELLOW` is or does, we have no way of knowing if that function call or macro invokation is relevant to the problem. If the problem is reproducible without it, then you should remove it. See [mre] for further information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `strcmp(yn, "yes")==0||strcmp(yn, "no")==0` evaluates to true if `yn` is "yes" or "no" so that would explain the first two tests.  You probably want:

```
do {
// ...
} while(!strcmp(yn, "yes"));
```

2. It does not explain the 3rd test "sjsbs".  This probably means `scanf("%s", &yn);` failed.  You should check the return value.
3. You did not tell us what `yn` is but it should be a array so leave out the '&'.  It would be particular bad if it's a `char yn` (see buffer overflow later).
4. Whenever reading a string with  scanf()`**always** specify the maximum field width to avoid buffer overflow.  If the input is smaller than what is being read by`scanf()`then a subsequent call would return that.  Consider using`fgets()`instead of`scanf()`.  You may still get partial input but with a sufficiently large buffer it will mostly just work.   The other option is discard everything in the input buffer till you hit a newline or EOF (using` getchar()` for instance).

```
char yn[3+1];
// ...
if(scanf("%3s", yn) != 1) {
    printf("scanf failed\n");
    break;
}
```

5. Use constants instead of magic values especially related ones 3+1 and 3.  You seem new at this so don't worry about this quite yet but this is how you would fix that:

```
#define YN_LEN 3
#define str(s) str2(s)
#define str2(s) #s

// ...

char YN[YN_LEN+1];
// ...
if(scanf("%" str(YN_LEN) "s", yn) != 1) {
// ...
```

6. I encourage you to format your code consistently (`do {` and `} while` should be at the same level, and I prefer compact code so more of it fits on the screen t a time (i.e. remove all those blank lines).